# How can I get a new Graphics2D object after I've read back a file from serialization in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing

I am getting a `Null pointer Exception` upon calling a Graphics2D object after reading a saved object back from disk. This is expected since I had to make the Graphics2D object transient to serialize my object. Upon loading I'd like to get a new valid Graphics2D object, so I can call my draw procedures without getting a null pointer. Any nice way to do this? If not, I've got a way to get around it, but it is nasty. I'd rather do it directly.

Thanks in advance.

The class:

```
public class GrafPanel extends JPanel implements Serializable 
{
    private transient Graphics2D grafCanvas;
    private GrafSession gFrame;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GrafPanel
     */
    public GrafPanel(GrafSession frame)
    {
       gFrame = frame;

    }

    public void setOwner(GrafSession gs) {gFrame = gs;}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        grafCanvas = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (GrafObject graf: gFrame.getGrafObjectList()){
            graf.drawGraf();
        }

      }

    public Graphics2D getGrafCanvas(){return grafCanvas;}

}
```

The call that throw the `Null pointer Exception`:

```
public void drawGraf(){
        double xMin = gStuff.getXMin();
        double yMin = gStuff.getYMin();
        double xMax = gStuff.getXMax();
        double yMax = gStuff.getYMax();
        Graphics2D gc =  Graphics2D)getOwner().getGrafPanel().getGrafCanvas();  //null pointer for gc here
...
```

Comment: Java does a lot of under  the hoods stuff when it comes to graphics, the graphics2d object you have is just an interface, I doubt it can be serialized. Try instead to save whatever information you require to rebuild it.

Comment: You don't, and you shouldn't be maintaining a reference to any system generate `Graphics` context anyway.  You should be passing `graf.drawGraf` the `Graphics` context that it should be using to paint to.  Serialising Swing objects this way is generally a bad idea, as it can cause issues with references to the native peer and should be avoid, all the time

Comment: 1) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 2) If the app. needs to serialize a graphic, I'd suggest saving it as PNG format (an image).

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. By getting rid of the getGrafCanvas() method completely, and passing the context instead, I was able to solve my problem. Thanks to everyone else for their comments also. All were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You defined Graphics2D as transient:

```
private transient Graphics2D grafCanvas;
```

Which means you are not serializing the object itself. So when you deserialise the object, you get object's default value i.e. null and on that null object you are trying to call method and hence NullPointerException.

You should use existing Graphics2D object if you already have one using [readResolve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#a5903) method or you could manually initialize it (worse option!)